# Find Data Drift in SQL Server Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have an SQL Server table with following fields:

```
Id int
PName varchar(30)
PValue decimal(10,2)
```

Once the data is loaded into this table, I wanted to run a query on "PValue" which is decimal type that should give the drift values. Please go through the following example data

```
Id   PName  Pvalue 
1     A     15.2
2     A     15.8
3     A     17.9
4     A     14.2
5     A     21.0
6     A     53.2
7     A     14.4
8     A      1.6
9     A     16.8
```

Now I want the query to return the data records of

```
6     A     53.2
8     A      1.6
```

A sudden rise or fall of the value when compared with previous records and later records.
Please help in providing an SQL Query to get this type of data.

Comment: Nothing in your example gives any clue why these two records are anything special.

Comment: Could you give us more detail about your question?

Answer (score 1):

If you have to do this in SQL you could do something like ths;

```
SELECT id, PName, PValue,
       CASE 
          WHEN ABS(PValue - AVG(PValue) OVER (PARTITION BY PName)) > 
               STDEV(PValue) OVER (PARTITION BY PName)
          THEN 1
          ELSE 0
       END AS deviates
FROM #TEST
```

Where #Test is your example data;

```
CREATE TABLE #TEST (Id int,
                    PName varchar(30),
                    PValue decimal(10,2))

INSERT INTO #TEST (id,PName,PValue) 
VALUES (1,'A',15.2),
(2,'A',15.8),
(3,'A',17.9),
(4,'A',14.2),
(5,'A',21.0),
(6,'A',53.2),
(7,'A',14.4),
(8,'A', 1.6),
(9,'A',16.8)
```

it shows where you deviate by more than 1 standard deviation from the mean.

Other options could be to write a .net CLR function if you need a more specific definition of what a "drift" is - that might give you a lot more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is take advantage of the R or Perl languages built into SQL Server and run queries to determine data drift as you outline. [Here's an article on SQLTips](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4880/sql-server-data-access-using-r--part-1/) showing how to find outliers in the data using R.

In your case, you're looking at both a min & max, so you'll want to combine the two examples in the article.

Comment: Its not a min &  max, I wanted to find the records which are abnormal when compared with previous record value and next record values. I am using dotnet as a programming language so can't use R or Perl here. If possible needed a SQL Query.

Comment: I said min and max, but min and max as outliers beyond the standard deviation, above or below. That's what you're looking for. Check the article.